# /usr/bin/env and Capistrano 3 failures in Rails Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm running capistrano (v3) to deploy to my production and a part of the output is below:

```
[dd854ece] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/deploy/apps/ap_production/releases/20140207003504/tmp/cache ] on myserver (redacted)
[dd854ece] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/apps/ap_production/releases/20140207003504/tmp/cache ]
[dd854ece] Finished in 0.153 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

I don't understand what is going on. env prints the set variables, and it can be used to run a command in a new environment, but last, it also is used, as here I think, to launch the right executable.

So what is the command/executable it's supposed to be launching? What are the square brackets for?

Thanks.

Comment: Alright, the square brackets are a bash test construct (man test?). But that doesn't explain what is going on here.  More research.

Comment: I found the following in a [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/08cxgLwUeIo) The test command (man (1) test) is aliased as `[` in most systems, that's what you see when you see shell scripting with lined like `if [ -e somefile]` (testing if some file exists, for example)

"That's exactly what we're doing in Capistrano, and that `(failed)` indicates that the directory, and symlink does not exist (i.e that it's not a directory, or not a symlink.)" from Lee himself. Unfortunately, that post is the key to my problems, but I don't understand it; the dir exists.

Comment: Maybe there's a missing if?

Comment: Hours of googling? ; )  Maybe I should put my energy elsewhere?  Anyway, this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) explains this construct:     *Similarly, a condition within test brackets may stand alone without an if, when used in combination with a list construct.*

`var1=20
var2=22
[ "$var1" -ne "$var2" ] && echo "$var1 is not equal to $var2"

home=/home/bozo
[ -d "$home" ] || echo "$home directory does not exist."`

Comment: So the line is a test, but the weird thing is I can't see what the action is that is taken after the test, but I guess it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comments. Apparently, it does exactly what it's supposed to do.